# getMap() in google map application in Android

Tags: android

I tried to call getMap() in my application and always get error at the line

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

The activity for displaying the GoogleMap is implement as a fragment. What could be wrong?
My whole activity is shown below.

```
 package sg.SanThit.TrackMe;

 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuInflater;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

 public class MyDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
 private TrackerInfo trackerDetailInfo;
 GoogleMap map;



public MyDetailsFragment() {    
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment)      
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (map == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Google Maps not available", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FragmentActivity` instead of `public class MyDetailsFragment extends Fragment`.

Below is sample code that loads a map :

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

   map = ((SupportMapFragment)      
  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
     }
```

Here `R.layout.activity_map` is the XML file containing fragment for map.

Comment: When I change to FragmentActivity I have problem at fragment transaction from the main activity to the detail activity. At Fragment fragment = new MyDetailsFragment();

Comment: Since now your `DetailsFragment` class extentds `FragmentActivity`, change it to `FragmentActivity fragment = new MyDetailsFragment();`.